# Was the Church of St Simeon the Elder at Aleppo built while Simeon was still alive or decades after his death?

Tags: christianity, building

I recently read in Diarmaid MacCullochs 'A History of Christianity' that the pillar dweller and hermit, Simeon had a church built around him, almost like a "living exhibit in a Christian zoo". However this contrasts other sources which have the church as being built decades after his death (his death being in 459 AD and the church being built in 475 AD). Which of these correct? Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to History Stack-Exchange. Great question, +1

Comment: i wasnt able to find you any specifics, but i know that there are many instances of churches from this time period and later taking 10-20- even 100 years to complete, so it not a stretch in my mind that they started building the church around him, or created a smaller structure, and finished the church in 475.

Comment: ive found further articles just stated its date of consecration was in 475 ad. but there seems to be no records or references of the actual construction start date.

Answer (score 1):

The text you have read refers to Simeon Stylites the Younger, who appears (according to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=yziOAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA285&dq=qalaat%20Seman&pg=PA285#v=onepage&q=qalaat%20Seman&f=false) and to a *Life* written around his own time) to have had a monastery built around him while he was alive. But as the aforementioned source says (as most other, apparently), the Church of Simeon Stylites the Elder was built as a posthumous memorial.